# Can't find where I am going wrong in adding months to a date in php

Tags: php

I am using date_add() function to add some months to the current date. While this working fine, when put in a loop, the months keep on adding to the previous result instead of the current date. Please help me

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $month = $row['month'];
    $temp = $current;
    date_add($temp,date_interval_create_from_date_string($month . " months"));
    $vm_id = $row["id"];
    $date_string = $temp->format('Y-m-d');
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO scheduled_dates (child_id,vaccine_month_id, 
    date) VALUES ('$id', '$vm_id', '$date_string')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $insert_query);
}
```

As you can see above, $current is storing the current date. In order to prevent it from changing in the date_add() function I am using a temporary variable $temp. But still the output is like it is adding months to the previous generated date instead of the current date. Please help me.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes sir, thank you for pointing to the solution. It was my bad, I didn't know how to search for this particular topic because I didn't know where I was going wrong. So I decided to ask the problem myself. I'll do a thorough search from next time before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$current` is an instance of the `DateTime` class. Class instances are "copied" by reference when using `=`, meaning `$temp` holds the very same instance as `$current`.

To circumvent this, you can use the `clone` keyword to create a copy instead:

```
$temp = clone $current;
```

Further reading: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php